# Sub menu in responsive menu won't push down the menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Wordpress with a Bootstrap theme and there's a problem with the responsive menu that I need some help with.

The problem is that the sub menus are floating over the menu instead of pushing it down. I guess it's because the sub menu is floating (float: left) but whatever I try won't solve the problem.

[image]
[image]

*html:*

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-header-collapse in">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-90">
            <a title="Foo" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Foo       
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                // more li elements
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS comes from Bootstrap which will be pretty space consuming if I put it in here.
If you need more code please comment and try to be specific.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because layout missing. Try to add `overflow:hidden` to the parent of the floating elements

Try some of this rules. Use **only one** of them

```
zoom:1; /*not a valid*/
height:1%;
display:inline-block;
element:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Tried to add overflow:hidden to the containing li element (which is the ul's parent) but that hides the whole sub menu...

Comment: @holyredbeard Hm... Try rules I listed higher. Element - is a class of your parrent

Comment: Should I apply them on the parent element? Just so I get it right - in this case it's the li element that holds the sub menu (ul), right?

Comment: @holyredbeard Yes. Apply it to parents with the floating child elements

Comment: Tried them all but no difference :/

Comment: @holyredbeard Please add your css and full HTML. Maybe another reason of this issue